# Is the value returned by the Collections.empty() methods always constant?

Tags: java, list, collections, static, implementation

This returns `true` in my trite little example:

```
List<Object> a = Collections.emptyList();

System.out.println(a == Collections.emptyList());
```

Is there an instance where a previous call to `Collections.emptyList()` might not equal `Collections.emptyList()` on a subsequent call? Is the result constant?

The implementation suggests so:

```
public static final List EMPTY_LIST = new EmptyList<>();

public static final <T> List<T> emptyList() {
    return (List<T>) EMPTY_LIST;
}
```

But how safe is it to rely on it outside of this particular implementation? The documentation doesn't explicitly state that it is constant.

Comment: Do you mean to ask "is the value returned a constant"?

Comment: What is the meaning of `final`?  Also see javadocs *Implementations of this method need not create a separate List object for each call.*

Comment: @flakes The note in the documentation is included in the accepted answer for duplicate question.  Even if I reopen this question, there is not really anything more to answer is there?